# Is it possible to find the 99th percentile using other percentiles?

Tags: distributions, mean, quantiles, percentage

I have the 10th, 20th, 25th, 30th, 40th, 50th (I assume this is the same as the mean), 60th, 70th, 75th, 80th and 90th percentile values of a data set. This is for the distribution of salaries in the UK, which I assume is a Bell curve, but I might be wrong.

I would like to know the 99th. Is there a formula or an online tool for this?

Thank you and all the very best!

Comment: It is very unlikely that salaries across the UK are normally distributed - [Table 5 of this ONS dataset](https://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/earningsandworkinghours/datasets/ashe1997to2015selectedestimates) shows quite visible right-skewness in full-time employee pay. In this case the mean salary will be higher than the median.

Comment: Without making any other distributional assumptions, it will be difficult to obtain the 99th percentile simply from other percentile values. One might want to consider other data sources.

Comment: The median (50th percentile) is substantially less than the mean.  In terms of equivalenced household disposable income (not salaries),  the mean is about $1.23$ times the median: see https://www.ons.gov.uk/resource?uri=/peoplepopulationandcommunity/personalandhouseholdfinances/incomeandwealth/bulletins/householddisposableincomeandinequality/financialyear2020/f990c4d9.png

Comment: In terms of the survey of personal incomes, the pre-tax income (not just salaries) of those at the 99th point seems to be of the order of 3 times that of those at the 90th point https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/percentile-points-from-1-to-99-for-total-income-before-and-after-tax   You will not be able to deduce that from the data you have

Comment: I interpret the question as: "Given these eleven percentiles, what is a reasonable estimate for the 99th percentile?" -- and in that form, I think it is reasonable and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume your data come from a Gaussian distribution (bell curve) then yes, you can get the 99th percentile from others.

- Set $\mu = q_{50\%}$. We are here using the fact that the median $q_{50\%}$ of a Gaussian is equal to it's mean $\mu$.
- Set $\sigma = \frac{q_{75\%} - q_{25\%}}{1.34896}$. We are here using the fact that the interquartile range $q_{75\%} - q_{25\%}$ of a Gaussian is 1.349 times its standard deviation $\sigma$.

Then you can get any quantile using the formula

$$ q_{\alpha} = \mu  + \sigma \times z_{\alpha}$$ where $z_\alpha$ is the corresponding quantile of a standard normal distribution, which you can find on tables online. For the 99-th quantile, you have $z_{0.99} = 2.326$.

However, if I may make a remark, I think the Gaussian distribution may not be the best fit for a salary distribution, which is usually skewed and heavy tailed. A Pareto distribution, for example, may be a better fit.

To get the Pareto quantiles you then must use the formula
$$ q_\alpha = x_0 (1 - \alpha) ^{- \frac{1}{k}}\,\,  .$$

- First find the $x_0$ and $k$ parameters of the Pareto distribution. For instance: $$k = \frac{\log(0.75) - \log(0.25)}{q_{75\%} - q_{25\%}}\,\, \textrm{ and } \,\,x_0 = {q_{50\%}}\times {0.5 ^{\frac{1}{k}}}\,\, .$$
- Then use the same formula again to get $q_{99\%} = x_0 0.01 ^ {-\frac{1}{k}}$ where you plug in the $x_0$ and $k$ values you found.

A log-normal distribution could also be a good candidate for the salaries distribution.

Comment: This is technically correct, but misleading without major caveats.  Salaries would have to fit one of these distributions *very closely indeed* for the suggested extrapolations to be at all meaningful.  If the OP wanted e.g. an interpolation to the 45th percentile, then a calculation like this would be a good approach.  But the 99th percentile is well outside the range of the data points OP has — well into the upper tail of the distribution, which is very likely (in general, but especially in this case) to behave  differently from other parts of the distribution.

Comment: I guess you are right. And even if data do come from a gaussian or Pareto distribution, the confidence interval for the 99% quantile could be huge as a tiny change in $\sigma$ or $k$ would yield a very large change in the quantile.

Comment: This interpretation of the question was posed and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48973.  Comments and methods using all percentiles are posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022.  Another solution is described at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130156.